# Weinsteins proof of the Milin Conjecture

Tags: complex-analysis

I am currently trying to work out the details in L. Weinstein's proof of the Milin conjecture (and hence the Bieberbach conjecture). Here is what I have managed to work out so far:

Let $f\colon \mathbb D\to \mathbb C$ be normalized schlicht und suppose $f_t(z)=f(z,t)$ is a Löwner-chain for $f$ i.e.

1. $f_0=f$
2. $f(z,t)=\mathrm{e}^t z+\sum_{k=2}^\infty a_k(t)z^k, \quad a_k(t)\in \mathbb C, z\in \mathbb D, t\geq 0$,
3. $\log\left(\frac{f(z,t)}{\mathrm{e}^t z}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k(t)z^k$, and $c_k(\infty)=2/k$,
4. $\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{\dot{f}(z,t)}{zf'(z,t)}\right)>0$ for every $z\in \mathbb D$.

Here $'$ and $\dot{}$ denote the partial derivatives w.r.t. $z$ and $t$ respectively.

For $z\in \mathbb D$ let $w=w(z,t)$ be implicitely defined via
\begin{equation}\label{eq:defw}
\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}=\mathrm{e}^t \frac{w}{(1-w)^2}    
\end{equation}
i.e.
$$
w(z,t)=k^{-1}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-t}k(z)\right)
$$
where $k(z)=z/(1-z)^2$ is the Koebe function. Using $k(w(z,t))=\mathrm{e}^{-t}k(z)$ we have
$$
k'(w(z,t))\cdot \dot w(z,t)=-\mathrm{e}^{-t}k(z)=-k(w(z,t)) 
$$
and therefore
\begin{equation}\label{eq:ableitungw}
\dot w(z,t)=-\frac{k(w(z,t))}{k'(w(z,t))} = -w(z,t)\frac{1-w(z,t)}{1+w(z,t)}=-w\frac{1-w}{1+w}.
\end{equation}
Let
$$
M(z):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{4}{k}-k|c_k(0)|^2\right)(n-k+1)\right)z^{n+1}
$$
Using the compactness of the class of normalized schlicht functions we can rearrange the generating function above and get
$$
M(z)=\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{4}{k}-k|c_k(0)|^2\right)z^k.
$$
Using the fundamental theorem of calculus, $w(z,\infty)=0$ and $w(z,0)=z$ we have
$$
M(z)=\int_{0}^\infty -\frac{\mathrm{e}^t w}{(1-w)^2} \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left[\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{4}{k}-k|c_k(t)|^2\right)w^k\right] \ \mathrm d t.
$$
For $r\in (0,1)$ let $\zeta:=r\mathrm{e}^{i\theta}$ and
\begin{equation}\label{eq:defp}
p(\zeta,t):=\frac{\dot f(\zeta,t)}{\zeta f'(\zeta,t)}.    
\end{equation}
The Cauchy formula now implies
\begin{align*}
\dot c_k(t) &=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\int\limits_{\partial B_r(0)} \log\left(\frac{f(z,t)}{\mathrm{e}^t z}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{z^{k+1}} \ \mathrm d z =\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{\partial B_r(0)} \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\left[\log\left(\frac{f(z,t)}{\mathrm{e}^t z}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{z^{k+1}}\right] \ \mathrm d z \\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{\partial B_r(0)} \left(\frac{\dot f(z,t)-f(z,t)}{f(z,t)}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{z^{k+1}} \ \mathrm d z=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{\partial B_r(0)} \left(\frac{\dot f(z,t)}{f(z,t)}-1\right)\cdot \frac{1}{z^{k+1}} \ \mathrm d z \\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{\partial B_r(0)} \frac{\dot f(z,t)}{f(z,t)}\cdot \frac{1}{z^{k+1}} \ \mathrm d z-\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{\partial B_r(0)} \frac{1}{z^{k+1}} \ \mathrm d z. 
\end{align*}
Noting that
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{\partial B_r(0)} \frac{1}{z^{k+1}} \ \mathrm d z=0,
$$
for $k\geq 1$ we have
\begin{align*}
\dot c_k(t) &=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{\partial B_r(0)} \frac{\dot f(z,t)}{f(z,t)}\cdot \frac{1}{z^{k+1}} \ \mathrm d z=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\dot f(\zeta,t)}{f(\zeta,t)}\cdot \frac{1}{\zeta^k} \ \mathrm d\theta.
\end{align*}
With the definition of $p$ and property 3. of the Löwner-chain we have
\begin{align}\label{eq:ableitungc}
\dot c_k(t) &=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} p(\zeta,t)\frac{\zeta f'(\zeta,t)}{f(\zeta,t)}\cdot \frac{1}{\zeta^k}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} p(\zeta,t) \left(1+\zeta\left(\frac{f'(\zeta,t)}{f(\zeta,t)}-\frac{1}{\zeta}\right)\right)\cdot \frac{1}{\zeta^k} \ \mathrm d\theta \notag \\ \notag
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} p(\zeta,t) \left(1+\zeta \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left[\log\left(\frac{f(z,t)}{\mathrm{e}^t z}\right)\right]_{z=\zeta}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{\zeta^k} \ \mathrm d\theta \\ \notag
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} p(\zeta,t) \left(1+\zeta \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left[\sum_{j=1}^\infty c_j(t)z^j\right]_{z=\zeta}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{\zeta^k} \ \mathrm d\theta \\ 
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} p(\zeta,t) \left(1+\sum_{j=1}^\infty jc_j(t)\zeta^j\right)\cdot \frac{1}{\zeta^k} \ \mathrm d\theta
\end{align}
Since the above integral is independent of $r\in (0,1)$ we finally have
\begin{equation}\label{eq:ableitungc2}
\dot c_k(t)=\lim_{r\to 1}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} p(\zeta,t) \left(1+\sum_{j=1}^\infty jc_j(t)\zeta^j\right)\cdot \frac{1}{\zeta^k} \ \mathrm d\theta.
\end{equation}
Using this expression for $\dot c_k(t)$ and former results we have
\begin{align*}
M(z) &=\int_{0}^\infty -\frac{\mathrm{e}^t w}{(1-w)^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{4}{k}-k|c_k(t)|^2\right)w^k\right] \ \mathrm d t \\
&=\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{e}^t w}{1-w^2}\frac{1+w}{1-w} \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[c_k(t)\overline{c_k(t)}\right]w^k+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (4-k^2|c_k(t)|^2)w^k\frac{1-w}{1+w}\right) \ \mathrm d t \\
&=\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{e}^t w}{1-w^2}\frac{1+w}{1-w} \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\lim_{r\to 1}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} p(\zeta,t) \left(1+\sum_{j=1}^\infty jc_j(t)\zeta^j\right)k\overline{c_k(t)\zeta^k} \ \mathrm d\theta \right.\right. \\
&\hspace{1cm}+\left.\lim_{r\to 1}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \overline{p(\zeta,t)} \left(1+\sum_{j=1}^\infty j\overline{c_j(t)}\zeta^{-j}\right)\cdot kc_k(t)\zeta^k \ \mathrm d\theta\right)w^k \\
&\hspace{1cm}+\left.\sum_{k=1}^\infty (4-k^2|c_k(t)|^2)w^k\frac{1-w}{1+w}\right) \ \mathrm d t \\
\end{align*}

This is where I am currently stuck. In his original paper Weinstein proceeds to claim that we can write
$$
M(z)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{e}^t w}{1-w^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty A_k(t)w^k \ \mathrm dt
$$
where
$$
A_k(t):=\lim_{r\to 1} \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \operatorname{Re}(p(\zeta,t))\left|1+2\sum_{j=1}^k jc_j(t)\zeta^j-kc_k(t)\zeta^k\right|^2 \ \mathrm d\theta.
$$
No matter what I am doing I seem not to be able to arrive at this conclusion using my previous calculations. Does anybody see what might be wrong with my calculations or have a hint how one might arrive at the desired conclusion?

Thanks in advance.